# Where to buy 2012 SE Lager parts?

Tags: parts

Two years ago, I got hit by a car. I was fine, but my bike's fork and front tire were destroyed, so I got a new bike. Now [this bike](http://www.sebikes.com/archive/2012/lager) has been sitting outside for 2 years. If I wanted to replace everything but the frame, what would I search, and where would I get the parts? Assume I know nothing about bikes, but I'm very handy with tools. I also have access to a machine shop and any "normal" tools, but the only bicycle-specific tool I have is a chain tool and tire levers. I imagine it's probably not worth it (financially), but I think it's worth it to learn more about bikes and bicycle repair. Also, I welcome any other tips, suggestions, or advice.

Note: I brought the bike to a shop. They were skeptical I'd be able to salvage the frame, but they inspected it and concluded it wasn't damaged.

Edit: I'm in Boston, MA, USA

Comment: Those parts are pretty standard and the link has many of them.  Not worth it financially.

Comment: Yeah, but for example, the website says: "Fork: Cr-Mo Straight Leg w/ Fender Mounts & Wide Tire Clearance"

But I still have no idea what to look for when buying one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most bicycle parts are fairly standard, and your bike doesn't look like an exception. There are several mail order stores and local shops that sell bike parts, just pick one. This site is fairly fanatical about not making recommendations, but just knowing your location could help.

Good places to start reading about bike maintenance and repair are http://sheldonbrown.com and http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/.

Comment: Thanks! Those look like great resources. If this is the wrong place to ask, should I delete the post?

Comment: In my opinion this is a perfectly good question, many active users just don't like product or shop recommendations.

Comment: Anyway, knowing even which continent you're on helps with shopping questions. Many of my favourite Germans will ship everywhere, but it is going to be expensive for longer distances.

Comment: @ojs if you disagree with closing product recommendation you'd bet better off [asking a question in meta](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/) rather than asking for downvotes.